# comma usage before 'so'

Tags: usage, conjunctions, commas

> Workers should be included in the planning for new factories or the introduction of robots into existing plants **,** **so** they can participate in the process.

I personally think that the comma before 'so' is not necessary because it is more appropriate without comma when 'so' clause, which is from **so** to **process**, is an adverbial clause.

For example, we don't use 'comma' before 'in order that': We must work together in order that agreement can be reached on this issue.

The comma (,) before 'so' is okay?

Comment: Sometimes the use of a comma to mark a pause is a stylistic choice, making it easier for the reader to make sense of a long sentence. In my opinion, the comma before _so_ is needed.

Comment: If it has to remain one sentence, I would skip the comma.  But in my opinion it's better to split this into two sentences. "Workers should be included in the planning for new factories or the introduction of robots into existing plants. That way they can participate in the process."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma in question is not *required*, but it's certainly not *banned*. It does serve a valuable purpose: without it, it's easy to start reading the "so" clause with the wrong understanding, thinking that it explains why robots should be introduced into existing plants.

> *... the introduction of robots into existing plants so they can participate in the process...*

Of course, if the reader thinks hard about it, they probably realize that "the process" means "the process of planning," referred to at the start of the sentence, not the process of what's done in the factories. But it's better not to first confuse the reader and then expect them to unconfuse themselves.

As mjjf suggests, we can probably get the most usable results by breaking up the sentence.